# Black Ops:  list of differences between standard and HC mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Everybody knows the basics — less health, blue-on-blue fire, no HUD. 
But what are specifics? How much less health? What other differences are there? How does the game style change?

Comment: What is the blue-on-blue fire ?

Comment: @Luc: friendly fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click this link for the full changes: [Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hardcore)